react: filtering filtered array of object
I have an array of objects which has a structure like this
export const CardContents =[
    {
        id:1,
        brand:'Akko',
        product:'Product 1',
        img:Icon1,
        price:100,
        category:'Keycaps'
    },
    {
        id:11,
        brand:'Press Play',
        product:'Product 1',
        img:Icon1,
        price:100,
        category:'Keycaps'
        },
    {
        id:12,
        brand:'Zifriend',
        product:'Product 1',
        img:Icon1,
        price:100,
        category:'Keycaps'
        },
   {
        id:2,
        brand:'Ajazz',
        product:'Product 1',
        img:Icon2,
        price:100,
        category:'Switch'
    },

i want to make a sidebar for filtering my filtered array.
so i tried to filter my array by the category and sidebar filter function using this.
    const filteredData = CardContents.filter(CardContent => CardContent.category === 'Keycaps') 

    const [item, setItem] = useState(filteredData)

    const menuItems = [...new Set(filteredData.map((content) => content.brand))]

    const filterItems = (cat) => {
        const newItems = filteredData.filter((newcontent) => newcontent.brand === cat )
        setItem(newItems)
    }

this is my sidebar
function CategorySidebar({menuItems, filterItems, setItem}) {
  return (
    <div className="hidden md:flex md:basis-1/3 lg:basis-1/4 flex-col p-2 bg-white rounded-lg self-start sticky top-24">
    <h1 className='font-medium mb-2'>
        Brand
    </h1>
    <ul>
    {menuItems?.map((content) => (
        <li className='mb-1' onClick={() => filterItems(content)}>
            <label htmlFor={content.brand} className='flex items-center'>
                <input type="checkbox" className='mr-1' />
                {content}
            </label>
        </li>
    ))}
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li onClick={() => setItem()}>
            <label htmlFor="" className='flex items-center'><input type="checkbox" className='mr-1' />See all</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

but the problem is when i click the category its not working
so how do i filtering my filtered array?

It looks like () => filterItems(content) is passing in the entire object, not the category or brand property.

React needs you to set a unique key property on the top-level element returned by your map function.

One issue with the initial implementation, is that you are not storing the selected brands, thus every time you select a brand you will only filter based on the latest selection. You need to keep track of the selected brands so you can filter on all of them.
I took your initial implementation and tweaked it a bit so it will work. I understand that you may have more than one components rendering the cards and the filter items, I've combined them for now just to demonstrate how the functionality should be for this to work.
See code below:
const CategorySidebar = () => {
    const filteredData = CardContents.filter(CardContent => CardContent.category === 'Keycaps')

    const [item, setItem] = useState<any>(filteredData)
    const [selectedBrands, setSelectedBrands] = useState<string[]>([]);

    // @ts-ignore
    const menuItems: any[] = [...new Set(filteredData.map((content) => content.brand))]


    const handleItemClick = (brand: string) => {
        let brandsValue: string[] = []
        if (selectedBrands.includes(brand)) {
            brandsValue = selectedBrands.filter(i => i !== brand)
        } else {
            brandsValue = [...selectedBrands, brand]
        }

        const newItems = filteredData.filter((newcontent) => brandsValue.includes(newcontent.brand))
        setSelectedBrands(brandsValue)
        setItem(newItems)

    }

    const selectAllBrands = (e: any) => {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            setItem(filteredData);
            setSelectedBrands(menuItems);
        } else {
            setSelectedBrands([]);
            setItem([]);
        }
    }


    return (
        <div
            className="hidden md:flex md:basis-1/3 lg:basis-1/4 flex-col p-2 bg-white rounded-lg self-start sticky top-24">
            <h1 className='font-medium mb-2'>
                Brand
            </h1>
            <ul>
                {menuItems?.map((content, index) => (
                    <li className='mb-1' key={`${content}_${index}`}>
                        <label htmlFor={content.brand}
                               className='flex items-center'>
                            <input type="checkbox" className='mr-1' checked={selectedBrands.includes(content)}
                                   onChange={() => handleItemClick(content)}/>
                            {content}
                        </label>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label htmlFor="seeall" className='flex items-center'>
                        <input id="seeall" type="checkbox" onChange={selectAllBrands} checked={menuItems.length === selectedBrands.length} className='mr-1'/>
                        See all
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div className="card-container">
                {item.map((item: any, index: number) => (
                    <div key={index} className="card">
                        <h2>{item.brand}</h2>
                        <p>{item.product}</p>
                        <p>Price: {item.price}</p>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

Items remain the same (i've removed the img's as I don't have the Icons.
export const CardContents = [
    {
        id: 1,
        brand: 'Akko',
        product: 'Product 1',
        price: 100,
        category: 'Keycaps'
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        brand: 'Press Play',
        product: 'Product 1',
        price: 100,
        category: 'Keycaps'
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        brand: 'Zifriend',
        product: 'Product 1',
        price: 100,
        category: 'Keycaps'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        brand: 'Ajazz',
        product: 'Product 1',
        price: 100,
        category: 'Switch'
    },]

